# How to display Unicode characters on Adafruit SSD1306 using Arduino IDE?

Tags: unicode, arduino, adafruit

I am willing to display a non-ASCII character in Adafruit SSD1306. The corresponding character set is in Unicode. Their [library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/) does not show where actually the mapping between ASCII & pixel drawing is done. If it was there, I'd've written code to display the characters that I need.

The hardware library depends on [Adafruit GFX library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library); even this library doesn't explain how the mapping is done.

So, which part of the actually maps an ASCII & pixels on display?
**OR** Any idea to display Unicodes directly?
**OR** How'd you get started if pixel by pixel configuration is needed?

I am using Arduino IDE, NodeMCU, Adafruit SSD1306 128x64 I2C monochrome LED display. The text that am trying to display is large and so, am not willing to it in BMP image way.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having difficulty understanding how I can add a cent symbol.

Comment: @EdHayes3, not yet; still decoding.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping between ASCII & pixel drawing is done in the font files.

See:

- Adafruit-GFX-Library/Fonts/
- Adafruit-GFX-Library/fontconvert/
- Adafruit-GFX-Library/gfxfont.h
- Adafruit-GFX-Library/glcdfont.c

So maybe you can create your own characters or font to display what you need.